# Starting grails in jetty server

Tags: java, spring, grails, jetty

I'm trying to start grails war (out of a fresh grails application), which I got after running the command:

```
grails dev war
```

I moved the this war to the jetty `webapps` and ran:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

and I got the following exception (a huge one):

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#77ea806f' of type [grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter] while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#77ea806f': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#77ea806f' of type [grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter] while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#77ea806f': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
```

I tried to change the build.gradle to reflect the spring-boot to be a `jetty` one like this:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
```

However, I ended up in getting the same result. Could anyone please let me know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use grails version > 3. Grails spring boot already contains embedded tomcat, you can replace tomcat with jetty (you already done this according to post above)

To run it just type

java -jar war file here